# FileSystemWatcher monitoring 2 directories. Change log increased by 1 per change, so when one file changes in console it pops up many times?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, directory, duplicates, filesystemwatcher

So I've got a large directory of different folders and I only have to monitor one at a time, the one that needs to be monitored is determined by certain info that I get from a completely seperate file in a seperate directory. This file can be updated with a different piece of info which therefore would mean the directory I monitor for changes will change. I've got all this working however it introduced a strange error. Lets call the individual file always being monitored for job number - Current job:
So when I see a file change in the directory intially loaded up (one of many job folders) it pops up once saying its changed in my console, perfect!. But when Current job file is altered and saved it says in console that it has been, great! However, in the job folders of all jobs, I'm now monitoring a different folder (determined by info in current job) and any changes in this folder pop up in console 2 times. Then if current job documents changed, this issue is 3, then 4, then 5 linearly increasing.
Any one run into similar or could pick out what I've goofed? Or even guide me in stopping dupes?

Heres the code: (Not a programmer, it will probably look messy - Very new and tasked to do this for work):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;


namespace EKMasterMonitoring
{
    class Program
    {
        //These values are being accessed at multiple methods in the program so simpler to declare them in the class allowing everything to easily call them
        public static DateTime modification = File.GetLastWriteTime(@"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Master\Zeichnungsdaten");
        public static DateTime creation = File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Master\Zeichnungsdaten");
        public static string Spacer = "\r\n----------------------------------------------------\r\n";

        public static string path = "";
        public static string AreaOfMonitor = "";
        //This is for monitoring in  method "Monitor Directory" I've declared it in class as it has to be disabled by another method seperate to "Monitor Directory"
        public static FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();


        public static string ProgramChange = @"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Master\Daten";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Runs method to grab current job as well as monitor it incase it changes
            ProgramSwapMonitor(ProgramChange);
            GetCurrentJob();

            // shouldn't need no more string path = "";
            path = AreaOfMonitor;
            MonitorDirectory(path);
            

            //Bool for the Loop just ensuring hitting the keyboard or anything daft wont close the program
            bool Running = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Type 'quit' to exit program");
            //This was mildly lazy but also I had a weird issue that naming it path solved, Don't really understand but it worked... ANYWAY - This is just storing the path to be used for monitoring
            

            while (Running)
            {
                
                string exit = Console.ReadLine();

                if (exit.ToUpper() == "quit".ToUpper())
                {
                    Running = false;
                }

            }
        }
        private static void GetCurrentJob()
        {
            //This gets the file
            string CurrentJobPath = @"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Master\Daten\dnocontainer.cfg";

            //This makes it so it only reads the 5th line of the notepad and ignore everything else
            string line = File.ReadLines(CurrentJobPath).Skip(4).Take(1).First();
            //This is getting rid of all parts of the line I don't care about
            line = line.Replace(" ", "").Replace("(STRING)Dno=", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace(";", "");

            //This isn't necessary but I like it okay
            string JobName = line;
            //Testing To prove its behaving
            Console.WriteLine(JobName);
            //This is making a path to the exact folder for the job currently running
            AreaOfMonitor = @"C:\Users\SIMPSJSH\Documents\Master\Zeichnungsdaten\" + JobName;
            Console.WriteLine(AreaOfMonitor);
            
    

        }
        private static void ProgramSwapMonitor(string ProgramChange)
        {
            // Create a new FileSystemWatcher and set its properties.
            FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Path = ProgramChange;

            /* Watch for changes in LastAccess and LastWrite times, and 
               the renaming of files or directories. */

            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
               | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

            // Only watch text This File
            watcher.Filter = "dnocontainer.cfg";

            // Add event handlers.
            watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
            watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

            // Begin watching.
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }
        // Define the event handlers.
        private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine(Spacer);
            
            //This disables the directory monitor, then changes the active job in its memory, then restarts the directory monitor so it can now monitor the new location.
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents= false;
            GetCurrentJob();
           
            MonitorDirectory(path);


        }

        private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is renamed.
            Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
            GetCurrentJob();
        }
        
        //AS MONITORING 2 SEPERATE DIRECTORIES WE NEED 2 SEPERATE INSTANCES OF FILE SYSTEM WATCHER
        //Break
        //Break
        //Break
        //Break

        public static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
        {
                fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;                           
                path = AreaOfMonitor;

                fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;


                //Allows monitoring of subdirectories. - Not needed as shouldn't be any:
                //FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

                //Splitting off the intial info from the change log
                Console.WriteLine("\r\n \r\n \r\n - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - \r\n        Begin Change Log\r\n \r\n \r\n");

                //Declaring the filters, I don't really know why its needed for the monitoring of changes, creation, deletion ECT but it is.
                fileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;
                

                //Calling the SystemWatcherFunctions
                fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
                fileSystemWatcher.Error += new ErrorEventHandler(OnError);

                Console.WriteLine("This is monitoring {0}", path);
                //enables the monitoring
                fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
             
        }
        private static void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            //This is for the sizes and file info. We are grabbing the resutls but also creating a converted version so I can't display in MB for large file with accuracy
            var info = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            var size = Convert.ToInt64(0);

            //declaring to be used, double allows decimals. 64bitInt does not.
            double MBSIZE = 0;
            //This is to avoid potential error. Ensures the info we are grabbing is in the direct directory and no sub ones.
            if ((info.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) != FileAttributes.Directory)
            {
                size = info.Length;
            }
            //This is for making it into megabytes for unnecessary user friendliness
            if (size > 1000000)
            {
                MBSIZE = Convert.ToDouble(size);
                MBSIZE = MBSIZE / 1000000;

                Console.WriteLine("File Changed/Edited/saved: {0}\r\nwas modified on {1}\r\nit is {2} Megabytes in size\r\nIs was originally created on {3} {4} ", e.Name, modification, MBSIZE, creation, Spacer);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File Changed/Edited/saved: {0}\r\nwas modified on {1}\r\nit is {2} bytes in size\r\nIs was originally created on {3}{4} ", e.Name, modification, size, creation, Spacer);
            }



                              
        }
        private static void OnError(object source, ErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Show that an error has been detected.
            Console.WriteLine("The FileSystemWatcher has detected an error at {0}", modification);
            //  Give more information if the error is due to an internal buffer overflow.
            if (e.GetException().GetType() == typeof(InternalBufferOverflowException))
            {
                //  This can happen if Windows is reporting many file system events quickly
                //  and internal buffer of the  FileSystemWatcher is not large enough to handle this
                //  rate of events. The InternalBufferOverflowException error informs the application
                //  that some of the file system events are being lost.
                Console.WriteLine(("The file system watcher experienced an internal buffer overflow: " + e.GetException().Message));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the solution:

```
private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
            Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine(Spacer);

            //This disables the directory monitor, then changes the active job in its memory, then restarts the directory monitor so it can now monitor the new location.
            fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
            GetCurrentJob();
            MonitorDirectory(path);
            fileSystemWatcher.Changed -= FileSystemWatcher_Changed;


        }
```

To get the Monitor directory to update with the new location given I had to re-initalise it (run it) again. This is what I take to be the issue as adding that one line made this issue start, so my kind of not great but functional solution is each time you change the Currentjob.txt file you're making this method run, adding one more monitor directory. So what I've simply done is add the -=FSW_Changed line so one is added and immediately took away. Leaving with the updated location and only 1 result

Comment: I haven't looked at the code (that's just how I roll). However you are likely creating multiple instances and not stopping them when there is a change

Comment: @TheGeneral What would be a method of stopping a method from a completely seperate method? Only one spot where it might be happening as I'm staritng a method from within a seperate area. Maybe the methods being run more than once there?
 ```private static void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)

 { 
  Console.WriteLine("File: " + e.FullPath + " " + e.ChangeType);
            Console.WriteLine(Spacer);
             fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents= false;
            GetCurrentJob();
             MonitorDirectory(path); ```

Comment: Its only guess, but you could store the instance of the Watcher, and disable/dispose it before creating another one.. EDIT, what @nordenvall said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MonitorDirectory-method you're just adding more delegates to the FileSystemWatcher_Changed-method on fileSystemWatcher.Changed:

```
fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
```

That's why you get a linear increase of notifications everytime the current job document is changed.

Comment: As far as I'm aware the += is necessary for SystemWatcher and it didn't create the increasing return of changed until I got the auto swapping of directories up and running so I don't know what I could do about that

Comment: I think the problem is that you've a static SystemWatcher, that is only one instance for the whole class, when the current job is changed the MonitorDirectory() will set a new path to monitor:
  fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
but you will add more delegates to the same static method FileSystemWatcher_Changed everytime with:
  fileSystemWatcher.Changed += FileSystemWatcher_Changed;
If the intention is to just monitor the new path then I guess you should be able to just change += to = but if you still want to monitor the previous paths you'll need to refactor the class some more.

Comment: If thats the case then I'm gonna have to figure out how to make the program ignore repeats as trying to remove the plus sign gives "Error 1 The event 'System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.Changed' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -
"

Comment: This lead me to the easiest solution that I can't believe I didn't try. Gonna do an edit to the post to explain incase someone else is crap at coding and runs into this issue.